# Merging NumPyarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, array-merge

I am looking to merge NumPy array elements in a list into a single NumPy array. How can I do this?

This is how the list containing arrays is structured and the code I tried:

```
import numpy as np

baked_quad_vertices = []

A = (1,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,3,4,5)
A = np.array(A, dtype=np.float32)

B = (1,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,3,4,5,
     1,2,3,4,5)
B = np.array(B, dtype=np.float32)

baked_quad_vertices.append(A)
baked_quad_vertices.append(B)

Z = baked_quad_vertices
Z = np.vstack(Z)
print(Z)
```

I get:

```
[[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
 [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]]
```

I want:

```
[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.
 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
```

Optimally I'd want:

```
[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5.
 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5., dtype=np.float32]
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you want, try using `np.hstack` instead of `np.vstack`.

---

*Editor's note: original answer below is referring to [Revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/68070232/1) of the question:*

> This looks wrong as each numpy array is still separated, what does the ... mean?

In fact, when you print an array it looks just like that. The output of `np.vstack` returns an array so you should have an array. Try printing:

```
print(type(baked_quad_vertices[chunk_count]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Though it seems to give me an array within an array. I just want (number, number, number, data_type) at the end. Unless I just need to merge lists to do this? I added a simplified section to my original post.

Comment: Try using `np.hstack` instead of `np.vstack` then